# Scheme: When to use let, let*, and letrec?

Tags: scheme, let

What is the difference between let, let*, and letrec?

Please give thorough explanations and examples.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your best bet is to read the [official R5RS descriptions](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/) of `let`, `let*`, and `letrec`.

In short, however:

```
(let ((x 2))
 (let ((x 3) (y x))
  y) => 2

(let ((x 2))
 (let* ((x 3) (y x))
  y) => 3
```

So the difference between `let` and `let*` is `let` will evaluate all the bindings with respect to the level above (so it doesn't matter what order they're listed in) while `let*` does it sequentially. `(let* ((x a) (b y)))` is equivalent to `(let ((x a)) (let ((b y)))`.

`letrec`, on the other hand, allows you to bind recursive values. So you might write a recursive function that you only want to be within the function scope and bind it to a name using `letrec`.