# Did Javascript execution context always have two phases (creation and execution)?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, interpreter, execution, hoisting

In JavaScript Understanding the Weird Parts ,the genesis of a particular execution context was explained in reference to two phases:

1. Creation phase - declarations are prioritized and initialized with undefined values
2. Execution phase - where assignments are resolved

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005098/why-does-javascript-hoist-variables/15014769#15014769) to a related question, the author refers to the interpreter making two passes on the source code.

Has this always been a feature of JS or is it more recent phenomenon related to more modern JS engines which act as JIT compilers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, everything has to be created before it can be used.

And yes, this has been the behaviour of JavaScript since the [first standard edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf).

But no, modern engines are not interpreters that "*make two passes on the source code*" any more, they use a parser that extracts the declarations and executable  commands in a single pass.