# How is it that Javascript is both interpreted language and support Hoisting?

Tags: javascript, compilation, execution, hoisting

JavaScript is an interpreted language, it does not compile the code before-hand, it interprets it at the time of execution.
Yet JavaScript supports Hoisting, How can it move all the declarations at the top without even compiling the whole program even once. How does this Hoisting and execution actually works??

Comment: It goes through two phases- declaration and execution. During the declaration phase, hoisting happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620041/how-does-hoisting-work-if-javascript-is-an-interpreted-language, This might help you