# Naming a formerly anonymous function breaks

Tags: javascript

Why does this not work:

```
$(document).on('click','a',myFunction);
var myFunction = function() {
   debugger;
}
```

When this does:

```
$(document).on('click','a',function() {
   debugger;
}
```

I've started to learn more by naming all my anonymous functions and breaking them out into their own separate named functions.

Comment: Oh, it's because I have to define the function before I reference it. It has to be above in the source code order.

Comment: But isn't there a way to hoist the function declaration?

Comment: Function *declarations* are always hoisted. But what you have there is not a declaration, it's a function *expression*. See the article linked from the bottom of my answer for details.

Comment: The page says that Function Declarations can not appear in Block ({ ... }).  I think what this is telling me is that I shouldn't use Function Declarations inside of another function, and thereby it would place all functions in the window scope, which of course would be bad.

Comment: No, nested function declarations are fine (and desirable). That quote refers to blocks like those of `if` and `for` statements; I guess `FunctionBody` is like a special kind of block, and declarations are allowed there.

Comment: I think the answer might be to use function myFunction() {} instead of var myFunction = function() {}

Comment: Philip, both methods are useful, just take hoisting differences into account when choosing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saying:

```
var myFunction = function() {
   debugger;
}
```

you need to say:

```
function myFunction() {
   debugger;
}
```

This will declare the function on the first pass so that it can be referenced during program execution.

Answer (score 4):

You have to swap the lines:

```
var myFunction = function() {
   debugger;
}
$(document).on('click','a', myFunction);
```

Otherwise, you would be [assigning `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725546/variable-hoisting) as the event handler, as the variable `myFunction` doesn't have a value yet when you were passing it to `.on`.

Also: assigning a function to a variable like that doesn't make it named, it's still an anonymous function, just stored in a variable. A named function would be:

```
var myFunction = function someName() {
    debugger;
}
```

See [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/) for more details.

Comment: Wow.  JavaScript never ceases to surprise me.  That's why I ask these fundamental questions, because I always learn something I never expect.

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks for the edit, that links makes the answer a lot better.