# Naming an anonymous function breaks my code

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

[I asked a similar question over a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749845/naming-a-formerly-anonymous-function-breaks).
But I can't figure this out.

This works:

```
$('#PlayArea').droppable({
    drop: function( myEvent, myUI ) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

But this doesn't:

```
function myDroppable() {
    this.drop = function( myEvent, myUI ) {
        debugger;
    }
};
$('#PlayArea').droppable(myDroppable);
```

Comment: With your setup, you would have to do `$('#PlayArea').droppable(new myDroppable());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myDroppable = {};
myDroppable.drop = function( myEvent, myUI ) {
   debugger;
}
myDroppable.tolerance = 'pointer';
myDroppable.hoverClass = 'ui-state-highlight';
$('#PlayArea').droppable(myDroppable);
```

This way you don't use colons as assignment operators.

Answer (score 2):

`droppable` takes an object literal, not a function. These two snippets are not equivalent, what you're actually doing is something like this (it's easier to see it's wrong this way):

```
$('#PlayArea').droppable(function myDroppable() {
    this.drop = function( myEvent, myUI ) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

If you want to use a named function, make it return the configuration object that's accepted by `droppable`.

Comment: I'm trying to use the equals sign instead of the colon to assign the 'drop' method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use, As `droppable` takes an object literal, thus return it.

```
function myDroppable() {
    return {
        drop: function (myEvent, myUI) {
            debugger;
        }
    }
};
$('#PlayArea').droppable(myDroppable());
```

### OR

```
var myDroppable = {
    drop: function (myEvent, myUI) {
        debugger;
    }
};
$('#PlayArea').droppable(myDroppable);
```

Comment: in this case, shouldn't you make the last line `$('#PlayArea').droppable(myDroppable());` so the function is actually called, instead of passed as the parameter?

Comment: Is there a way to say myDroppable.tolerance = 'pointer', using the equals sign as the assignment operator instead of the colon?

Comment: @Phillip, You can use `$("#PlayArea" ).on( "drop", function( event, ui ) {} )`. We have limitation as droppable accept object literal. So you can try `$("#PlayArea" ).on( "drop", new myDroppable().drop)`