# Why single var is good in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why use one var declaration for multiple variables and declare each variable on a newline consider is a good programming behavior?

```
// bad
var items = getItems();
var goSportsTeam = true;
var dragonball = 'z';

// good
var items = getItems(),
    goSportsTeam = true,
    dragonball = 'z';
```

Comment: It's personal preference.

Comment: It's just style, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not considered 'good' or 'bad'. It's a matter of preference.

The guy who built the code quality tool JSLint, Douglas Crockford likes it.

One 'advantage' it might have is that it avoids the possibility of [variable hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725546/variable-hoisting). In JavaScript all `var` declarations move to the top of their scope automatically.

Here is why Crockford thinks the second option is better:

> In languages with block scope, it is usually recommended that variables be declared at the site of first use. But because JavaScript does not have block scope, it is wiser to declare all of a function's variables at the top of the function. It is recommended that a single var statement be used per function. This can be declined with the vars option.

Comment: My understanding is that either style is a variable declaration and would be hoisted.  How does the latter style avoid it?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein In the latter style, you can't have other code between the variable declarations, I'll clarify on Crockford's _opinion_ on that.

Comment: seriously, I found the 2nd style is so inconvenient sometimes. e.g. I need to look for where the variable from if it is not defined within one screen visible area.

Answer (score 1):

It's a preference, I wouldn't say good or bad. Yes JSLint complains about it, I don't really like how it complains about `for` loop variables being inline as well. The reason that it was put in JSLint was to prevent possible hoisting confusions.

Also in some cases declaring all of your variables at the top will lead to a slightly smaller file. Consider the following:

```
var a = 10;
a++;
var b = 20;
```

After Google Closure being run over it

```
var a=10;a++;var b=20;
```

As opposed to this if we pull `b`'s declaration to the top.

```
var a=10,b;a++;b=20;
```

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit (aside from style preference, I guess) is that it will prevent you from writing code that suffers from unintended variable hoisting consequences.

Take this example:

```
var foo = function(){alert('foo');}
function bar(){
  foo();
  var foo = function(){alert('foobar')};
  foo();
}
bar();
```

By reading this code, the intent of `bar` appears to be as follows:

1. Call the outer `foo` function to alert the string `'foo'`.
2. Create a local variable, `foo`.
3. Call the local `foo` function to alert the string `'foobar'`.

In reality, what happens is this:

1. The local variable `foo` is hoisted to the top of the `bar` function.
2. `foo` now actually refers to the local variable instead of the outer variable of the same name. But since the local hasn't been assigned yet, its value is undefined. Hence, when you try to invoke `foo`, you'll get a TypeError.
3. Nothing. Because you threw an error. That's it. Your code broke.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for Crockfords preference have been well made and are valid. I am just beginning to return to the first format now however, as I believe that for experienced developers who understand variable hoisting and are not likely to fall foul to it, there are 2 advantages that I can think of:

1. When new variables are added to the list of definitions, diffing is made easier. This means you are likely to experience fewer merge conflicts (simple though they may be to resolve) and less cognitive load when analysing diffs. For similar reasons I have also been converted to dangling commas, which I would never have expected xD
2. As @ldsenow identified, it can make searching for variable definitions more simple. You will always be able to search for `var <name>` and get the result you want and nothing else.