# What does the 'in' keyword in javascript mean?

Tags: javascript

I found this code:

```
if (!("aa" in window)) {  
    alert('oh my god');
    var aa = 1;  
}  
alert("aa" in window);
alert(aa);
```

This code the second alert is  alert `true`,but,the third alert is 'undefined',and the alert in the 'if' is not run. Why?

I think the reason is the `in`; what is its effect?

I searched on Google, but found nothing, because Google thinks the word ‘in&srquo; is a filter word.

We always use the `in` in loops, but, frankly speaking, I use it but don’t really understand it.

Comment: I guess that a variable named `aa` was created in the global context. `alert("aa" in window);` returns false for me but `aa = "foo"; alert("aa" in window);` returns true.

Comment: oh my god,i think i lost some code when i wroten the question...

Comment: I think this is an entirely different question now if you are asking about alerts. I'd recommend editing the question title to a better description of your problem.

Comment: @LIXer I edited my answer to answer the new question but please try to fix your question immediately next time or to ask a new one when you realize the code you gave first time wasn't the right one for you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This tests if the `window` object has a property (filled or not) whose key is `"aa"`.

This operator is very useful because it works even if the value is `undefined` :

```
window.aa = undefined; // or just aa=undefined if you're in the global scope
console.log('aa' in window); // logs true
```

It also works if the property isn't enumerable :

```
console.log('length' in []); // logs true
```

In your case, there may not be an `aa` value, but if the alert shows you true, the property was added to `window`.

[**MDN reference on in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Note that the `for...in` statement is different in that it doesn't really use the `in` operator but is a specific construct.

**[MDN reference on for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)**

---

**EDIT :** an explanation of your edited question (very different from the first one) :

Your confusion seems to arise from the fact you declared the `var aa = 1;` in a block. You should know that the scope of a variable in JavaScript is either a function of the global scope and that declarations are hoisted. So your code is in fact equivalent to

```
var aa = undefined;
if (!("aa" in window)) { // aa is in window, so we don't enter here
    alert('oh my god');
    aa = 1;  
}  
alert("aa" in window); // yes, the property exists, it's true
alert(aa); // aa is still undefined
```

Comment: You're welcome. But you should remove the EDIT part of your question : questions aren't supposed to include the answer on SO. Let's make this clean for other future users coming by.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the alerts in order:

- **alert #1** is never reached because `("aa" in window) === true` so the `if` boolean condition is false.

JavaScript has [*function scope*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) and the variable `aa` is ["hoisted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725546/variable-hoisting) up to the top of the scope first, so it *is* defined.

- **alert #2**

`"aa" in window` is true because the variable was added to the window object when it was hoisted up. Equivalent to just writing:

```
var foo;
"foo" in window (which === true)
```

- **alert #3**

From the [Standard ECMA-262 ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) :

> A variable statement declares variables that are created as defined in 10.5. Variables are initialised to **undefined** when created. A variable with an Initialiser is assigned the value of its *AssignmentExpression* when the VariableStatement is executed, not when the variable is created.

So `aa` is undefined since the assignment was never executed.

Comment: thank you, i know the function scope but i consider no function in my code, oh no ,my javascript is so weakly

Comment: Happy to help! It was an interesting question. Since there is no block scope in JavaScript (block scope defined as inside a `{...}`) the variable will be available outside the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

`in` checks if property exists in `Object`

```js
// in the below snippet they are checking if 'aa' property exists in 'window' Object . Since variables are function declarations are hoisted. you'll never enter inside if block .

var aa = undefined ;
if (!("aa" in window)) {   //2 => 'aa' property exists 
    alert('oh my god');  
    aa = 1;         // 1 =>  hoisted 
}
```