# Searching toFixed with "in" operator - How does the "in" operator work on primitives?

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I started reading YDKJS for fun - and found that he's written:

we can do stuff like:

```
var num = (1.2).toFixed(1)
```

so - this means that toFixed is being invoked as a member method from an integer value.

So why doesn't this work??

```
"toFixed" in 1.222
```

But this works:

```
"toFixed" in new Number(1.222)
```

Comment: `1.222` is a *primitive* - it doesn't have any methods. When you call `(1.2).toFixed(1)` that's being cast into a Number object.

Comment: so this is explicit coercion ??

Comment: yeah, rather quite implicit :)

Comment: Implicit, although it's a bit dubious whether it's coercion. `(1.2).toFixed(1)` is *almost* like `new Number(1.2).toFixed()` but you might not actually get an actual object, the environment might act *as if* you did that but not create, discard, and garbage collect an object.

Comment: @vlaz the optimization steps the engine takes are unrelated to the spec. They will behave *exactly* like that, the engine might optimize the constructor away in *both cases* (or it might not, who knows ...)

Comment: In case any one wants to look up that implicit coercion in the spec, it is in `7.1.13 ToObject` wich gets called by GetValue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the 'in' keyword in javascript mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831812/what-does-the-in-keyword-in-javascript-mean)

Answer (score 2):

Page 268 of the Es262 spec states:

> *RelationalExpression : RelationalExpression in ShiftExpression*
>
> [...]
>
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
> 4. Let rval be ? GetValue(rref).
> 5. **If Type(rval) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.**

So in other words: You can't use `in` on numbers. Thats just the way it is defined.

`new Number` however does not create a number, but a *number object* (an object that inherits from the `Number.prototype`).  That's why you can use `in` on it, cause its an actual object.

---

You can still do `12..toFixed()`, thats because of a very interesting construct in the spec: The abstract `GetValue` operation, which will be called when you access a property¹, does call `toObject` if the target (`12` in this case) is not an object, and that will then do the following:

> Return a new Number object whose [[NumberData]] internal slot is set to argument.

So in other words: `12..toFixed()` is *exactly the same* as `new Number(12).toFixed()`.

<sub>¹ interestingly accessing the property itself does not actually do that according to the spec, if you do `a.b` that will only look up the value of `a` and create a reference (`Reference(a, "b")`). The actual property lookup happens when `GetValue` gets called on it (however I don't know of any case were a Reference gets lost without calling `GetValue` on it).</sub>

Comment: _You can still do `12..toFixed()`_ Which is nice but the OP asked about floats. Like `1.3` or `1.2`. Then how can we do this?

Comment: @weegee there is no such thing as "floats" in js. "floats" are just numbers.

Comment: I know but I used the word to represent decimal values.

Comment: @weegee I don't get your point. There is no technical difference between `12..toFixed()` and `1.2.toFixed()`.

Comment: @weegee *all* numeric primitives in JS are represented as a IEEE 754 floating point number. Both `-2` and `0.5` have a sign, mantissa, and exponent represented in binary as per the same standard. There is no difference between the two numbers safe for what the values of those three components - any operation done on *any* primitive number will be resolved using the same mechanisms as with any other number.