# Java script:About function within an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

not sure whats the this used for:
"this.changeName = changeName;" if i delete this line the code doesn't work fine. But this line seems do nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor)
{
this.firstname=firstname;
this.lastname=lastname;
this.age=age;
this.eyecolor=eyecolor;
this.changeName = changeName;
function changeName(name)
{
this.lastname=name;
}
}
myMother=new person("Sally","Rally",48,"green");
myMother.changeName("Doe");
document.write(myMother.changeName);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your confusion is a result of `variable hoisting`. You should see this thread for discussion on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725546/variable-hoisting

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

`this.changename` assigns the private `changeName` function to the Objects instance. So, when you create a new Object of type `person`, person has the method `changename` because of `this.changename` which assigns `changeName` as the function to execute.

Comment: It doesn't assign it to the prototype, assigns it to the instance

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor)
{
this.firstname=firstname;
this.lastname=lastname;
this.age=age;
this.eyecolor=eyecolor;
this.changeName = function(name) {
this.lastname=name;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use :

```
this.changeName = function(name)
{
this.lastname=name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function changeName is a method on the object person, which you set when you say 
    this.changeName = changeName; 
this meaning the person object.

You're not using that function until you call it here 
    myMother.changeName("Doe");

In which you are changing the last name to "Doe"  So myMother.lastname = "Doe"

I'm kind of repeating what the others are saying, but hoping that it is more clear.