# JS cannot toggle elements Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var page = 1;
    $(".btnReadMore").click(function(){
        if(page==1){
            $('#aboutUsText').text('textone');
            var page=0;
        }else{
            $('#aboutUsText').text('text two');
        }
    }); 
});
```

I am fairly new to javascript, I am trying to toggle an elements text when you press a button, What am i doing wrong? Thanks :3

Comment: Don't declare again variable `page` in `if`, just initialize it `page = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using "var page = 1;" because it's a global variable and one should avoid global variable when possible because they are bad for performance.

```
$("#btnReadMore").click(function(){
    var textSpan = $('#aboutUsText');
    if (textSpan.attr("ShowState")=="2"){
        textSpan.text('textone');
        textSpan.attr("ShowState", "1");
    }else{
        textSpan.text('text two');
        textSpan.attr("ShowState", "2");
    }
});
```

In the above example, I declare my own custom attribute called ShowState and I save it on the label itself. Also, I switched the button an use an ID instead of class. Class is slow to access. ID is instant.

Checkout my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eLVTk/

Comment: This is working well in jsfiddle, However dosen't seem to be working when implimenting into my webpage. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/v7yrKSnS

Comment: Please change to <input id="btnReadMore" type="button" value="Read More" name="readmore" />. You should only use class attribute when necessary, hence I changed the button to use id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are re-declaring `page` within the function, the entire `.click()` event handler will **always** use the `var page = 0`. See [variable scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) and [variable hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725546/variable-hoisting).

As Dhaval stated in the comments, simply dropping the declaration will fix this:

```
 page = 0; // Instead of var page = 0
```