# A variable is visible in another block as well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
function ready() {
  $("#my_form").on("submit", function (e) {
    for (var j in someItems) {
      var element = $(someItems[j]);
      $("<input>").attr({type: "hidden", name: element.attr("name"), value: element.val()}).appendTo($(this));
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < someItems2.length; i++) { 
      // "element" is visible here ??????
      $("<input>").attr({type: "hidden", name: element.attr("name"), value: element.val()}).appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(ready);
jQuery(document).on("page:load", ready);
```

Why is the variable `element` visible in the second loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725546/variable-hoisting

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description

Comment: Scope of JavaScript variables is their parent function not blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the variables does not have `block` scope in JavaScript but `functional scope`

Please refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) article.