# Why does declaring a var inside a callback undefine the parameter? (Hoisting)

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, declaration, hoisting

```
$(function() {
    foo1("text");
    foo2("text");
}) 

function callback(func) {
    func();
}

function foo1(bar) {
    callback(function() {
        console.log(bar);       // "text"
        bar = "derp";
        console.log(bar);       // "derp"
    })
}

function foo2(bar) {
    callback(function() {
        console.log(bar);       // undefined
        var bar = "derp";
        console.log(bar);       // "derp"
    })
}
```

Why is that declaration of var bar  = "derp" undefining the parameter, that is accessed beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this code

```
function foo2(bar) {
    callback(function() {    
       console.log(bar);       // undefined
       var bar = "derp";
       console.log(bar);       // "derp"
    })
}
```

is actually

```
function foo2(bar) {
    callback(function() {  
       var bar;
       console.log(bar);       // undefined
       bar = "derp";
       console.log(bar);       // "derp"
    })
}
```

due to the variable *hoisting*. So even if you created a global `bar` variable inside the `foo1` call, a scoped variable `bar` is declared inside the inner scope of the `foo2` function. That's why the first `console.log` returns `undefined`

See also [Variable hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725546/variable-hoisting) on SO

Comment: Thanks.. "Hoisting" was the keyword here. That's really some unexpected behaviour if you never came in touch with it.

Comment: @xDreamCoding— "hoisting" is misleading jargon. Variable and function declarations are processed on entering an execution context and before any code is executed. Variables declared with *var* are initialised to *undefined*, therefore reading their value before assignment of a different value returns the value *undefined*.