# JavaScript - AngularJS Scope Issue: Object in the Global Scope Undefined in Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a event handler in my AngularJS directive:

```
angular.element($window).on("wheel", onScrollAction);
```

Before `onScrollAction` in my directive I have defined some variables, outside of the `onScrollAction` function itself because I don't want them assigned on every wheel event, as they shouldn't change.

```
app.directive('scroll', function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var elem = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.titletitle')).eq(1);
    var elemHeight = elem[0].scrollHeight;
    //so on until the 5th element
    //then object to store all the elements and their heights:
    var theObject = [{el:elem,elH:elemHeight},{el:elem2,elH:elem2Height},{el:elem3,elH:elem3Height},{el:elem4,elH:elem4Height},{el:elem5,elH:elem5Height}]
    var theActiveElem = theObject[0];
    var onScrollAction = function (event) {
    console.log(theActiveElem) //renders undefined
    console.log(elem) // renders the element
```

My question is, how come the `elem` is fine going from a global scope to a function scope, when `theActiveElem` is not and how do I fix it so I can do actions on `theActiveElem` in my event handler.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725546/variable-hoisting)

Answer (score 0):

This is really weird to me, would like an explanation...

My console log inside the event handler looked like:

```
        console.log(theActiveElem,theObject); //theActiveElement undefined
        thepatch = Math.floor(theoffset/theActiveElem.elH)
        if(thepatch==1){
            var theActiveElem = theObject[thepatch];
            console.log(theActiveElem);
        }
```

But as soon as I changed the `var theActiveElem = theObject[thepatch];` to `theActiveElem = theObject[thepatch];` it fixed.

I recognize that I shouldn't have declared it with `var` on that line, but why would that cause an error in the log a few lines up?

Anyway, this is resolved now.