# Hoisting order of precedence and variable mutation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap my head around a few things when it comes to hoisting and variable mutation.

1. Variable assignment takes precedence over function declaration
2. Function declarations take precedence over variable declarations

Function declarations are hoisted over variable declarations but not over variable assignments according to https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript. This is extremely confusing because I thought only variable declarations and function declarations get hoisted.

```
var double = 22;

function double(num) {
 return (num*2);
}

console.log(typeof double); // Output: number
```

so with hoisting it should look like

```
function double(num) {
  return (num*2);
}

var double;
double = 22;


console.log(typeof double); // Output: number
```

If variable assignment takes precedence over function declaration why isn't double = 22 above the function declaration? Another example

```
var double;

function double(num) {
  return (num*2);
}

console.log(typeof double); // Output: function
```

With hoisting pulling the function above the variable declaration the console should log undefined shouldn't it? With variable mutation the last assignment is what the program should execute.

Comment: Variable *name declarations* are hoisted, but variable *assignment* (with `=`) is never hoisted

Comment: Then what does "Variable assignment takes precedence over function declaration" mean?

Comment: @larryburns It makes no sense at all, really. An assignment and a declaration are two totally unrelated things, they don't "take precedence" over each other. I guess it's supposed to mean just that you can always assign a mutable variable, and it will hold the assigned value afterwards, regardless of where/how the variable was declared (with `var` or `function`).

Comment: Can anyone explain how in my last example even though function is hoisted above the variable declaration the output is still function instead of undefined?

Comment: @larryburns Because "takes precedence" doesn't refer to order, as in "is hoisted above the other". Declarations don't really have any order for our purposes, all variables are created at once (*that*'s what "hoisting" actually means). The precedence refers to the value that the variable is initialised with, `undefined` for `var`s and function objects for `function`s. The rule means that when there is a `function` declaration with the same name as a `var` declaration, then the variable is initialised as a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(From the comments)

> If variable assignment takes precedence over function declaration why isn't `double = 22` above the function declaration?

Variable name declarations are hoisted, but assignments (`=`) are never hoisted.

> Then what does "Variable assignment takes precedence over function declaration" mean?

It makes no sense at all, really. An assignment and a declaration are two totally unrelated things, they don't "take precedence" over each other. I guess it's supposed to mean just that you can always assign a mutable variable, and it will hold the assigned value afterwards, regardless of where/how the variable was declared (with var or function).

> How in my last example even though function is hoisted above the variable declaration the output is still function instead of undefined?

Because "takes precedence" doesn't refer to order, as in "is hoisted above the other". Declarations don't really have any order for our purposes, all variables are created at once ([*that*'s what "hoisting" actually means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32475965/1048572)).

The precedence refers to the value that the variable is initialised with, `undefined` for `var`s and function objects for `function`s. The rule means that when there is a `function` declaration with the same name as a `var` declaration, then the variable is initialised with the function.

Answer (score 0):

This should clarify what is meant:

```js
var myVar = 1;

outerFunc1();
outerFunc2();


function outerFunc1()
{

  innerFunc();    // works due to hoisted declaration

  function innerFunc()
  {
    console.log(myVar);
  }

  var innerFunc;  // function declarations take precedence

  innerFunc();    // works even if var innerFunc is declared
}

function outerFunc2()
{

  innerFunc();    // outputs undefined since myVar is redeclared locally (hoisted)

  function innerFunc()
  {
    console.log(myVar);
  }

  var myVar = 2;  // local declaration (AND initialisation)


  var innerFunc;  // function declaration take precedence

  innerFunc();    // outputs 2 even if var innerFunc is declared

  innerFunc = 1;  // this overwrites the function
  innerFunc();    // gives an error 'not a function'.
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*redeclared locally*".

Comment: @Bergi What don't you understand? `var myVar` is declared in global scope and redeclared in function scope as a local variable.

Comment: Oh, you meant that it's declared in `outerFunc2`, not in the `innerFunc` that is getting called in the line with the comment.

Answer (score -1):

As per MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#Only_declarations_are_hoisted

> JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations.

So let's rewrite your examples for a better understanding:

1.

```
var double = 22

function double(num) {
  return (num*2)
}

console.log(typeof double)
```

This can be read like:

```
// hoisted
var double

function double(num) {
  return (num*2)
}

// initialise
double = 22

console.log(typeof double)
```

2 & 3 Can be read exactly in the order as you have written them. In 2) the initialisation happens last, so it outputs `Number`. In 3) there is no initialisation at all, so the function is declared last, so it outputs `Function`.

So your confusion about the third example seems to be understanding the difference between declarations and initialisations.

---

EDIT: There is definitely some confusion with ordering (hence writing `this can be read like..`). While javascript technically hoists the functions first, you should still read your code as I have written, as functions take priority over the variable declarations. In other words, while technically the hoisting goes:

```
function double(num) {
  return (num*2);
}    

var double;    

console.log(typeof double); // Output: function
```

The function still takes priority, so it is better to read the other way around.

Comment: Function declarations are hoisted above variable declarations. There is no initialization in my last example. If the last double type is a variable in the document it should log as undefined, but it logs as a function.

Comment: Updated my answer.