# Javascript Hoisting and Additional Features

Tags: javascript

Good day all,

This is not a specific question, but a general one.

In particular, i am preparing for a Javascript related interview.  On Glassdoor, I saw someone mention that previously, "What is Javascript hoisting?" was a question that was asked.

In essence, I wanted to know what type material I should study on Javascript to know it to that depth.

Now, ideally, you would tell me to read a book and learn as much about Javascript such as if I were to be asked what hoisting was, that I would be able to answer it "naturally."

However, this raised an important thought with me, in that I know I have a limited amount of hours, and being able to study "smart" for interviews would be a good skill for future interviews, that may not necessarily test Javascript knowledge.

Is hoisting considered a "feature" of Javascript?  What are such phenomena called, and are there books that specifically highlight the key features of a language that distinguish it from most others.

This is a very vague questions, but in essence I want to find out a way where I can learn about in-depth features of a programming language without having to study from square one, up to that point.

Hope that made sense!

Best regards,
Andy

Comment: I'd recommend checking out Tyler McGinnis videos on advanced JavaScript. [This one specifically](https://youtu.be/Nt-qa_LlUH0) relates to your question.

Comment: thanks ^ I think adding "advanced" to a tutorial search is useful, as most tutorials can summarize concepts quite well rather than going into the documentation.

Comment: One devs feature is another devs bug.

Comment: Minor nit, but it's JavaScript. It's a good idea to spell the tech right.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could call it a feature. Back in the day, you needed to make sure you defined every function before it was called, and everything would be compiled in the order it was written: Think about something like `var myCat = new Cat(); function Cat() { ... }`, the code would throw an error at the `new Cat()` token (something like `undefined is not a constructor`), because, at the time `new Cat()` is executed, the `Cat` function is never defined. It's defined later in the code.

With hoisting, variable declarations are loaded into memory at compile time, and you can initialize and use variables/functions before they're declared, meaning you don't have to worry about this conflict. That's really all there is to it. It's effectively a compile-time optimization - something to make peoples' lives easier, like how `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` array iterations are largely deprecated (outside of closure compiled code etc.) because of the `Array.prototype.forEach` builtin.

You can read more about function hoisting on [MDN's Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

```js
// call to catName before declaration
catName("Chloe");

function catName(name) {
  console.log(`My cat's name is ${name}!`);
}
```

Comment: Everything is still compiled in the order it's written.

Comment: @DaveNewton Not sure I'd say that a multi-pass compiler respects any "order".

Comment: @Bergi Implementation-dependent; generally handled during linking phase anyway--as much as there is a linking phase, not sure I'd call it that in something like JS but end result is the same.

Comment: Hmm, that makes a lot of sense.  Then, how is the scope of the hoisted variables kept in check?  Is there a "scope tag" that is brought together, into memory, with the hoisted variable/function? Thanks.

Comment: An answer to my comment (to Herculean's post) from either of you would be nice :)  I think it's an important question for me to really understand what's really going on when the code is being run.  Thanks!

Comment: @AndyLiao, I really don't know much past what I mentioned - I did find [this blog post](https://hackernoon.com/scope-hoisting-in-javascript-19b991babc4f) that goes over scope and hoisting, but when it comes down to JS compilation, I'm in over my head!

Comment: Thanks!! Regardless, I don't think that they won't go that in-depth anyways.

Comment: @AndyLiao https://stackoverflow.com/a/32475965/1048572