# JavaScript Hoisting - Hoisted code after Memory Creation phase

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I was reading Kyle Simpson book: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/scope%20%26%20closures/ch4.md#functions-first.

But I don't fully understand this line ***"Notice that var foo was the duplicate (and thus ignored) declaration, even though it came before the function foo()... declaration, because function declarations are hoisted before normal variables."***

Let's say this is the code:

```
console.log(foo);     // The output is: foo() { return 2; }

function foo() {
    return 1;
}

function foo() {
    return 2;
}

var foo = 3;
```

I want to visualize what would be the output in JS Engine after Memory Creation phase. Will it be like this?

```
function foo() {
    return 2;
}

console.log(foo);
```

If yes, why `var foo = 3;` was ignored? There is no duplicate for `var` in the snippet. If no, can anyone please help me visualize what would be the output in JS Engine after Memory creation phase?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the text refers to

```
// scope creation
var foo; // the name was declared. Thrice.
foo = undefined; // from the var
foo = function foo() { return 1 }; // from the first declaration
foo = function foo() { return 1 }; // from the second iteration

// execution
console.log(foo);
;
;
foo = 3;
```

where `foo` is initialised with `undefined` due to the `var foo` declaration, but then gets overwritten by the initialisation value from  the `function foo` declaration which takes precedence - regardless of the order in which the declarations appeared in the code, `function` declarations overrule `var` declarations.

Comment: "*But in the book it says, functions are hoisted first, and then variables*" - oh well. Different approaches, some outcome. While I chose to say variables come first and then are overwritten, the book says "*multiple/duplicate var declarations are effectively ignored*", i.e. variables come second but don't overwrite functions. That's another reason why [hoisting is a bad metaphor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32475965/1048572), no code is "moved around" and nothing of this is observable, all that matters is the resulting state at the beginning of the execution.

Comment: Btw, you really should be reading [the second edition of the book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/ch5.md), not the first one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and the link. Really appreciate your effort :)

Answer (score 2):

- Function declarations

  1. Declare a variable with the same name as the function (this is hoisted)
  2. Assign the function to that variable (this is hoisted)
- `var` statements with associated assignments

  1. Declare a variable with that name (this is hoisted)
  2. Assign the value to that variable (this is **not** hoisted)

---

`var foo = 3` is not ignored.

The variable declaration (`var foo`) is ignored because the earlier function declarations already declared that variable. (i.e. because it duplicates the declaration of `foo`).

`foo = 3` is not ignored and does assign `3` to `foo` … it just does so **after** your `console.log` statement runs because it isn't hosited.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and help. Really appreciate your effort