# Safari: Unable to retrieve parameters of an async function

Tags: javascript, function, fetch-api

I just made a function that displays a dialog on the page in Javascript, this function is asynchronous because it loads the dialog which is a page in PHP. However, to display the message I need to pass parameters. This function works very well, but does not work at all on Safari, when I display the parameters, on Safari it returns "undefined", while on MS Edge, it returns the parameter values. I tried with another non-asynchronous function, and it displays parameters fine. Do you think Safari doesn't handle parameters for async functions or am I doing it wrong? Thank you very much to the people who will help me. (Sorry for my bad English).

Function :

```js
async function openDialogInfo(title, message, button) {
  alert(title + ' ' + message + ' ' + button);
  var title = (typeof title !== 'undefined') ? encodeURI(title) : 'Information';
  var message = (typeof message !== 'undefined') ? encodeURI(message) : 'Error retrieving message !';
  var button = (typeof button !== 'undefined') ? encodeURI(button) : 'Ok';
  if (title.length >= 3 && message.length >= 5 && button.length >= 3) {
    if (screen.width >= 720) {
      $("#out-popup-e").css({
        'opacity': '0'
      }).show();
    } else {
      $("#out-popup-e").show();
    }
    var params = `title=${title}&message=${message}&bouton=${button}`;
    var resp = await fetch('../../../popup/popup_ecars_info.php', {
      method: "POST",
      body: params,
      headers: {
        "Content-type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    });
    var out = await resp.text();
    if (resp.status == '200') {
      if (screen.width >= 720) {
        $("#out-popup-e").animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 400).html(out);
      } else {
        $("#out-popup-e").html(out);
        $(".center-popup").css({
          'bottom': '-700px'
        }).animate({
          'bottom': '0'
        }, 400);
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Error Message 2');
    }
  } else {
    console.error('Error message 1');
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="action" onclick="openDialogInfo('HELLO WORLD', 'New message for testing (don\'t work on Safari)')">TEST</button>
<button class="no-action" onclick="autreTest('New Message (work)')">New test</button>
```

Comment: The function takes 3 parameters, you're only calling it with 2 arguments. So `button` will be undefined.

Comment: What is `autreTest()`? If it's not relevant, why is it in the HTML snippet?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. In Safari the alert is `undefined undefined undefined` instead of `HELLO WORLD New message for testing (don't work on Safari) undefined`

Comment: @Barmar likely caused by hoisting the variables with the same name. Somewhat related (not _entirely_): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725546/why-variable-hoisting-after-return-works-on-some-browsers-and-some-not

Comment: @robertklep Yes, looks similar. There's also a known issue with nested functions defined inside `if`.

Comment: @Barmar This function just display an `alert()` with the parameters.

Comment: I understand. The problem has to do with the scope and initialization of hoisted variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're declaring new variables with the same names as the parameters. Since they're declared with `var` the declarations are hoisted to the top of the function, and the initial undefined value are overriding the parameters.

Either use different variables or just reassign them rather than re-declaring them.

```js
async function openDialogInfo(title, message, button) {
  alert(title + ' ' + message + ' ' + button);
  title = (typeof title !== 'undefined') ? encodeURI(title) : 'Information';
  message = (typeof message !== 'undefined') ? encodeURI(message) : 'Error retrieving message !';
  button = (typeof button !== 'undefined') ? encodeURI(button) : 'Ok';
  if (title.length >= 3 && message.length >= 5 && button.length >= 3) {
    if (screen.width >= 720) {
      $("#out-popup-e").css({
        'opacity': '0'
      }).show();
    } else {
      $("#out-popup-e").show();
    }
    var params = `title=${title}&message=${message}&bouton=${button}`;
    var resp = await fetch('../../../popup/popup_ecars_info.php', {
      method: "POST",
      body: params,
      headers: {
        "Content-type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    });
    var out = await resp.text();
    if (resp.status == '200') {
      if (screen.width >= 720) {
        $("#out-popup-e").animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 400).html(out);
      } else {
        $("#out-popup-e").html(out);
        $(".center-popup").css({
          'bottom': '-700px'
        }).animate({
          'bottom': '0'
        }, 400);
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Error Message 2');
    }
  } else {
    console.error('Error message 1');
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="action" onclick="openDialogInfo('HELLO WORLD', 'New message for testing (don\'t work on Safari)')">TEST</button>
<button class="no-action" onclick="autreTest('New Message (work)')">New test</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the new tip I am learning today. It works perfectly in the Chrome browser, but it only has this problem in the Safari browser.

Comment: @MerbinJoe Found this which provides more detail as to why this happens https://medium.com/@alsotang/a-hoisting-bug-in-the-async-function-in-safari-ba1ecc386b4a, turns out that this only happens in safari when shadowing parameters with var in async functions